# SQL -Oracle - Return results in the exact order on the input Entered in the BO Screen - Solution updated

Tags: sql, oracle, business-objects

I used the below query to get the Dateofbirth and Mark values.

```
SELECT b.Subject_name, a.Empnum, Dateofbirth,b.mark   
FROM Employee a, Subject b
WHERE a.Empnum = b.Empnum 
AND Empnum in (<promptval1>)
AND b.Subject_name in (<promptval2>)
```

I used this query in Business Object. Suppose if user enters  Subject name as MATHS, PHYSICS, CHEMISTRY and Empnum as 999, 998, 608, 611, 501 and then it will be translated to like this in BO

```
SELECT b.Subject_name, a.Empnum, Dateofbirth,b.mark   
FROM Employee a, Subject b
WHERE a.Empnum = b.Empnum 
AND Empnum in (999, 998, 608, 611, 501)
AND b.Subject_name in ('MATHS', 'PHYSICS', 'CHEMISTRY')
```

But what i need is, i would like to receive the data in the order which it entered.

Example: Here MATHS entered first, so i need MATHS with EMPNUM in the order entered(999,998,608,611,511). Even the empnum should display in the order entered.

I need output like this.

```
Subject_name Empnum dateofbirth mark
MATHS        999    1-JAN-2000   57
MATHS        998    1-JAN-2000   58
MATHS        608    1-JAN-2000   90
MATHS        611    1-JAN-2000   23
MATHS        501    1-JAN-2000   52
PHYSICS      999    1-FEB-2000   87
PHYSICS      998    1-FEB-2000   67
PHYSICS      608    1-FEB-2000   34
PHYSICS      611    1-FEB-2000   78
PHYSICS      501    1-FEB-2000   90
CHEMISTRY    999    1-JUN-2000   55
CHEMISTRY    998    1-JUN-2000   56
CHEMISTRY    608    1-JUN-2000   59
CHEMISTRY    611    1-JUN-2000   60
CHEMISTRY    501    1-JUN-2000   61
```

But the results are not coming in this way. The order by and group by will sort the results.

So i am not getting the above output

In the Business Object when they can enter all these inputs as 1 time, so it will be translated like above. So in the query i am thinking to apply some row number based on IN Clause.

Please note:  Input of the subject, Empnum might be more.. Here the subject input is only 3 and Empnum input is only 5.

Comment: I think you need to add audit trail fields such date_entered, date_updated, etc. in order to achieve the desired result

Comment: User enter all these input at the same time. Please refer the BO part, how that oracle Query is translated

Comment: In the Business Object when they can enter all these inputs as 1 time, so it will be translated like above. So only query i can get some rownumber based on IN Clause. But not sure how it to be acheived.                                                               Corrected the subject

Comment: There isn't anyway to transmute the order of  operands in an `IN` clause into the controlling values of an `ORDER BY` clause. Are you sure this is an actual requirement?

Comment: If the business requirement is to know the order of entering the data, you would have to treat that information that way, i.e. store some entry order information. E.g. if you have a form with rows and the order of rows has to be retained, then pass the row number into the tables, as an additional column and later use it for ordering or whatever else the business may require. If you have not stored any ordering information in the data, then Oracle DB has no way of retaining that order (as table rows are not stored in a specific order).

Comment: OK. On the fourth reading of your question, I think I finally got what you meant. The user is entering filtering criteria, and you would like to use the order of entering those criteria to order the query results.

Comment: Yes thanks for all of your time

Comment: Solutions should be entered as answers, not as edits to the question. But with the CTE approach you still need to join to the real tables to get the other columns; and as I noted and APC reinforced in my (now deleted) ordering isn't guaranteed when unnestinging the varrays. (And does this approach work at all from BO? Even with the extra `with` keyword?)

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**  `join` syntax, along with meaningful table aliases.

To get results in a particular order, you need an `order by`.  In this case:

```
SELECT s.Subject_name, e.Empnum, Dateofbirth, s.mark   
FROM Employee e JOIN
     Subject s
     ON e.Empnum = s.Empnum 
WHERE e.Empnum in (999, 998, 608, 611, 501) AND
      s.Subject_name in ('MATHS', 'PHYSICS', 'CHEMISTRY')
ORDER BY (CASE s.subject_name WHEN 'MATHS' THEN 1 WHEN 'PHYSICS' THEN 2 WHEN 'CHEMISTRY' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END),
         (CASE e.EmpNum WHEN 999 THEN 1 WHEN 998 THEN 2 WHEN 608 THEN 3 WHEN 611 THEN 4 WHEN 501 THEN 5 ELSE 6 END);
```

Comment: The subjects and Empnums are not constant.

Comment: I think the order should be based on the moment the rows were inserted (commited)...

Comment: In the Business Object when they can enter all these inputs as 1 time, so it will be translated like above. So only query i can get some rownumber based on IN Clause. But not sure how it to be achieved.                                                             Corrected the subject

Comment: @user3738664: The query is based on the information you gave (and your suggestion on using what is in the `IN` clause) and gives the result you've described as expected. As you can't use something you do not have, this is probably the best answer you can get, other than to change your data model.

Comment: I still consider this solution from @GordonLinoff better than using "sys.odci*" functions. You just have to generate the `ORDER BY` clause dynamically. If you do not like the use of `CASE` statement, then you can try `DECODE` instead, e.g. `DECODE( s.subject_name, 'MATHS', 1, 'PHYSICS', 2, 'CHEMISTRY', 3)`.

Comment: Updated the solution. Thanks for all of your time